# How to handle Azure Synapse "Try reducing the numbers of vcores requested or increasing your vcore quota"

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I ran into this issue below, when trying to run a simple pyspark script in Azure:

%%pyspark
df = spark.read.load('abfss://products@xyzabcstorageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/userdata1.parquet', format='parquet')
display(df.limit(10))

InvalidHttpRequestToLivy: Your Spark job requested 24 vcores. However, the workspace has a 12 core limit. Try reducing the numbers of vcores requested or increasing your vcore quota. HTTP status code: 400. Trace ID: 3308513f-be78-408b-981b-cd6c81eea8b0.

I am new to Azure and using the free trial now. Do you know how to reduce the numbers of vcores requested?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is the [config](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-development-using-notebooks.md#spark-session-configuration-magic-command), I am not sure if it helps since your are on free trial. you can probably try reducing the number of vCore through the config at the beginning of the notebook.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this problem by just closing the other notebook tabs. It will simply close that session.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue while trying to run a pyspark script and found that there are two ways to solve it:

1. Reduce your usage of the pool resources before submitting a new resource request
   by running a job or notebook
2. You can scale up the node size and the number of nodes

You can get more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1151904/invalidhttprequesttolivy-your-spark-job-requested)

Answer (score 0):

Found some relevant link from microsoft which can help  :

1. Reduce your usage of the pool resources before submitting a new resource request by running a job or notebook
2. You can scale up the node size and the number of nodes
3. or try this

[azure synapse analytics : apache spark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-concepts)

[Increase VM-family vCPU quotas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quotas/per-vm-quota-requests)